# how can I split channel [sample,[bam1, bai1],[bam2, bai2]] to [sample,[bam1,bai1]] and [sample,[bam2,bai2]] in nextflow

Tags: nextflow

transpose() gives [sample,[bam1,bam2]] and [sample,[bai1, bai2]]

flatten doesnt help either

also I want a operator to convert a channel like this way no matter the number of bam pair (if the input channel is [sample,[bam1, bai1]], then the output of this operation is just the input itself)

Comment: Could you not emit them from the previous process like that? Something like `set val("${sample}"), path("${sample}.bam"), emit: bam_ch; set val("${sample}"), path("${sample}*.bai"), emit: bai_ch`

Also, I've used really simple processes to manipulate files when I couldn't find the operators I've needed for relatively complex manipulations.